# setcookie() can't set a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

This is script.php which I run which directs the user to callback.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require_once 'OAuth.php'; 
require_once 'OAuthCurl.php'; 

$callback_url = "http://something/bio/callback.html"; 


$consumer_key = "<code>"; 
$consumer_secret = "<code>"; 

$oauth_request_token = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"; 
$oauth_authorize = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"; 
$oauth_access_token = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"; 

$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(); 
$test_consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $callback_url); 

$req_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer, NULL, "GET", $oauth_request_token);

$req_req->sign_request($sig_method, $test_consumer, NULL); 

$oc = new OAuthCurl(); 
$reqData = $oc->fetchData($req_req->to_url()); 

parse_str($reqData['content'], $reqOAuthData); 

$req_token = new OAuthConsumer($reqOAuthData['oauth_token'], $reqOAuthData['oauth_token_secret'], 1); 

$acc_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer, $req_token, "GET", $oauth_authorize); 
$acc_req->sign_request($sig_method, $test_consumer, $req_token);

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $reqOAuthData['oauth_token']; 
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $reqOAuthData['oauth_token_secret']; 

Header("Location: $acc_req"); 
?>
```

This is the callback.php
I'm trying to set a cookie on callback.php but the cookie is not getting set. 
I can't seem to understand why?

```
<?php

session_start(); 
$_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];
require_once 'OAuth.php'; 
require_once 'OAuthCurl.php'; 
require_once __DIR__ . '/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/TwitterOAuth/Exception/TwitterException.php';

use TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$callback_url = "http://something/bio/callback.php"; 

$consumer_key = "<code>"; 
$consumer_secret = "<code>"; 

$oauth_request_token = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"; 
$oauth_authorize = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"; 
$oauth_access_token = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"; 
//$authenticate_token = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";
//echo($authenticate_token);
//exit();

$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();


$test_consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $callback_url);

$params = array(); 

$acc_token = new OAuthConsumer($_SESSION['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'], 1); 


$acc_req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($test_consumer, $acc_token, "GET", $oauth_access_token); 
$acc_req->sign_request($sig_method, $test_consumer, $acc_token); 


$oc = new OAuthCurl(); 
$reqData = $oc->fetchData("{$acc_req}&oauth_verifier=".$_GET['oauth_verifier'].""); 

parse_str($reqData['content'], $accOAuthData); 
//$username = $accOAuthData[screen_name];
$_SESSION['username'] = $accOAuthData['screen_name'];         
$_SESSION['final_oauth_token'] = $accOAuthData['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['final_oauth_token_secret'] = $accOAuthData['oauth_token_secret'];
$final_oauth_token = $_SESSION['final_oauth_token'];
$final_oauth_token_secret = $_SESSION['final_oauth_token_secret'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];





/**
 * Array with the OAuth tokens provided by Twitter when you create application
 *
 * output_format - Optional - Values: text|json|array|object - Default: object
 */
$config = array(
    'consumer_key' => '<code>',
    'consumer_secret' => '<code>',
    'oauth_token' => $final_oauth_token,
    'oauth_token_secret' => $final_oauth_token_secret,
    'output_format' => 'object'
);
/**
 * Instantiate TwitterOAuth class with set tokens
 */
$tw = new TwitterOAuth($config);


$params = array(
    'screen_name' => $username,
    'count' => 5,
    'exclude_replies' => true
);

/**
 * Send a GET call with set parameters
 */
$response = $tw->get('users/show', $params);




$id =($response-> id);
$description=($response-> description);
$screen_name = ($response-> screen_name);


setcookie("test1", $screen_name, time()+3600*30);

/*Connection String*/
$hostname = 'something';
$database = 'twitter';
$username = '';
$password = '';


$conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(!$conn)
        {
            die("Unable to Connect localhost!".mysql_error());
        }
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database!".mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM twitter_tbl WHERE id = '". $id ."'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
                        { 


                        }
else
    {
    $sql='INSERT INTO twitter_tbl(description,screen_name,id,final_oauth_token,final_oauth_token_secret,timestamp) VALUES("'.$description.'","'.$screen_name.'","'.$id.'","'.$final_oauth_token.'","'.$final_oauth_token_secret.'",'.strval(time()).')';


    if(!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
                        {
                            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                        }
                        $bio_archives1 = 'INSERT INTO bio_archives(bio,screen_name,id,timestamp) VALUES("'.$description.'","'.$screen_name.'","'.$id.'",'.strval(time()).')';

                if(!mysql_query($bio_archives1,$conn))
                                    {
                                        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                                    }
  }

if( strlen($description) < 80)
{
    $newtext="is now ".'"'.$description.'"'." 'http://www.biostories.net/user.php?screen_name=".$screen_name."'";
                        $b = explode( "#tweeted", $newtext );
                        $txt = trim( $b[0] );
                        $url = trim( $b[1] );
                        $txt = substr( $txt, 0, 139 - strlen( $url ) );
                        $output = $txt . " " . $url;
}

else                    
{
    $description1 = substr($description, 0, 50);
    $newtext="is now ".'"'.$description1.'...."'." 'http://www.biostories.net/user.php?screen_name=".$screen_name."'";
                        $b = explode( "#tweeted", $newtext );
                        $txt = trim( $b[0] );
                        $url = trim( $b[1] );
                        $txt = substr( $txt, 0, 139 - strlen( $url ) );
                        $output = $txt . " " . $url;

}

$tw = new TwitterOAuth($config);
try{
$tw->post('statuses/update',array('status' =>$output));
}
catch(Exception $e) {
($e->getMessage());

}
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM twitter_tbl WHERE id = "'.$id.'"');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
$desc = $row['description'];
}
    if($desc === $description)
    {   

    }
    else
        {
            $query_update = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM twitter_up_tbl WHERE id = '". $id ."'"); 
            if (mysql_num_rows($query_update) > 0) 
              {

                  $query1 ="Update twitter_up_tbl SET description='".$description."' WHERE id=".$id."";
                  $sql1 = mysql_query($query1);

              }
            else
             {
                $update_sql = 'INSERT INTO twitter_up_tbl(description,screen_name,id,final_oauth_token,final_oauth_token_secret,lastupdate) VALUES("'.$description.'","'.$screen_name.'","'.$id.'","'.$final_oauth_token.'","'.$final_oauth_token_secret.'",'.strval(time()).')';

                if(!mysql_query($update_sql,$conn))
                                    {
                                        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                                    }

            }

            $query ="Update twitter_tbl SET description='".$description."' WHERE id=".$id."";
            $sql = mysql_query($query);

            $bio_archives = 'INSERT INTO bio_archives(bio,screen_name,id,timestamp) VALUES("'.$description.'","'.$screen_name.'","'.$id.'",'.strval(time()).')';

                if(!mysql_query($bio_archives,$conn))
                                    {
                                        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                                    }

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Did you check the HTTP response header? Try add: "setcookie("test1", $screen_name, time()+3600*30, false, true);"

Comment: How do i check it? I've added fasle, true but still no cookie is getting set

Comment: what is that? How do I use this?

Comment: Try [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the packets between server and browser to see if the cookie headers are properly sent and received.